# Python Selenium screenshot of captcha in popup modal

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, python-imaging-library

So I am trying to take a screenshot of a CAPTCHA that pops up on a website I am scraping. The python selenium screenshot method `driver.save_screenshot(fileLocation)` gets the screenshot of the entire site page.

I then switch to the current frame and get the get the location of the element using the following two commands:

```
element  = driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementXpath)
location = element.location
```

The problem I am running into is that the location method gets the location of the element on the renderable canvas which does not seem to match up with the screenshot image taken. So when I try to crop the CAPTCHA out with the commands below, I get some other part of the webpage as the cropped image.

```
#get element size information
size = element.size

#assign crop variables
left   = location['x']
top    = location['y']
right  = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

#crop, show, and save
im  = Image.open(filelocation)
im2 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)).save(cropFileLocation)
```

Am I missing something obvious?